# Adding list data to a .txt file and re-opening these lists where prompted

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have done some research and found various examples but as my python knowledge is so basic I do not understand them.

Is there a method for importing ONLY the lists to another python window as any import i try seems to import the list and then run that files functions which I don't want it to do? I only want the other python pages to import the lists to either show them or modify them further? I have no code for this but I presume it would be something such as

```
from 'filename' import task[],date[],description[]
```

The code this is on is as follows (Bear in mind I only want to lists. I don't want the other functions to be run)

```
import sys
import os
task=[]
date=[]
description=[]
def addtask():
    """adds a task to the task list"""
    print("Please re-enter your filename with .txt on the end.")
    f=(raw_input("filename: "))
    file= open(f, "w+")
    add=(raw_input("Enter a task: "))
    if add=="helpme":
        os.startfile("C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\Python coursework\helpme.txt")
        add=(addtask())
    else:
        file.write(add)
        task.append(add)
    add1=(raw_input("Please enter a date for this task: "))
    if add1=="helpme":
        os.startfile("C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\Python coursework\helpme.txt")
        add=(addtask())
    else:
        file.write(add1)
        date.append(add1)
    add2=(raw_input("Please enter a description of the task: "))
    if add2=="helpme":
        os.startfile("C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\Python coursework\helpme.txt")
        add=(addtask())
    else:
        file.write(add2)
        description.append(add2)
    a=(raw_input("would you like to add another?: "))
    if a=="yes":
        print(addtask())
    elif a=="helpme":
        os.startfile("C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\Python coursework\helpme.txt")
        add=(addtask())
    else:
        import choices
b=(raw_input("Would you like to add a task?"))
if b=="yes":
    add=addtask()
elif b=="no":
    import choices
elif b=="helpme":
    os.startfile("C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\Python coursework\helpme.txt")
    add=(addtask())
else:
    import choices
```

Hopefully that has come out correctly...
Note* the three lists are called `task[]`, `date[]` and `description[]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$ cat task.py 
task=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from task import task
>>> task
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Yeh that should work. Ill try see if it works shortly. Just fixing some other bugs/glitches

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. My update to the above question may shed some more light. You will be able to see all the code and I would only like to take data from the task,date,description lines

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the [ ] and it should work if you have defined those lists as variables in the other file.

Comment: Sorry that did not work. The lists are completely seperate to the functions on that page but if i simply type in from 'filename' import tasks: The program still runs all of the functions even though I only want to use the lists and leave the functions alone

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you import any module(file) in python with the import statement, you execute all the content in the file(the first time it is imported by the runtime, every other time just the reference to the first load is used).

file1.py:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

file2.py:

```
from file1 import mylist
```

Typically this doesn't matter, if you only have function and class definitions in a module. If there are other statements they get executed as well.

What you can't do is import a module change some list stored in the module, close the INTERPRETER(i.e. python), restart the interpreter and expect your changes to be still there -> no persistant storage. If you want to persist a list I'd recommend using the Pickle module